# Is @IonicPage decorator deprecated?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried to remove [@IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) decorator from my code and everything works fine. But I did not find about it in documentation. @IonicPage segment property doe not work. If I navigate to pages, then URL does not change, URL is always http://localhost (instead of http://localhost/page1). Page example:

```
@IonicPage({
    segment: 'page1'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page1',
  template: 'some content'
})
export class Page1 {

}
```

Comment: `@IonicPage` is not deprecated, but since it just allows your pages to be lazy-loaded, if you remove it from the pages, everything may still work... Have you also created a module for each page in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have a module for each page. And I import page module in AppModule

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed **rootPage** in **app.component.ts** 
from from an *imported component* to a *string*, it's not lazy loaded.

As @sebaferreras mentioned @IonicPage comes into play if you lazy-load.

When you lazy load pages in Ionic you add modules per page with their own **@ngModule**.
You use **IonicPageModule.forChild(PageName)** in the **imports: []** section,
instead of **IonicModule.forRoot(AppName)** in the top level **app-module.ts**